# Convert number to text in matrix (values) for Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have created an matrix and in the matrix, I have column called Traffic Spikes. That column have data of 0 or 1. I put that column in the values field in matrix visualization. Then I'm doing Max of Traffic Spikes. Is there way to turn 0 or 1 to Yes or No without impacting the Max of Traffic Spikes? I would like to keep the maximum

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column in the query editor with yes and no corresponding to 0 and 1

```
'YesNoColumn
= if [Traffic Spikes] = 0 then "Yes" else "No"
```

In the matrix you still use the Traffic Spieks column for the calculations but as column/row in the matrix you use the YesNoColumn.